# jQuery show/hide div onclick checkbox multiple

Tags: jquery, html, onclick, hide, show

My fiddle works, but what I need is for the hidden div to STAY displayed if I click multiple checkboxes. And I need it only to HIDE once NO checkbox is clicked anymore. So for example, I click the first checkbox, the div shows. I click the second, the div stays. I uncheck the second, the div stays. I uncheck the first (which means none are checked again) and the div hides. I tried using slideToggle but it doesn't hide once no checkboxes are checked anymore.

https://jsfiddle.net/6zsdLa5p/

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="ui-options" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" value="ui-options" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" value="ui-options" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" value="ui-options" />

<br /><br />

<div class="ui-options">
show me!
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ui-options {
display:none
}
```

JS:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    if($(this).attr("value")=="ui-options"){
        $(".ui-options").slideToggle(150);
    }
});
```

Comment: You can try go get the number of checked ones to know you want to hide/show your div using this:
  var someChecked = ($("input:checkbox[value=ui-options]:checked").length>0)
Let me know it is ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
// find the <input> elements whose type is equal to 'checkbox',
// bind a change event-handler to those elements:
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {

  // selecting the <div> element(s) with a class of
  // 'ui-options', then using a ternary within the square brackets,
  // if there are checked <input> elements, we use the slideDown
  // method (to show) if there are no checked <input> elements
  // we use the slideUp method (to hide):
  $('div.ui-options')[$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length ? 'slideDown' : 'slideUp']('fast');
});
```

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  $('div.ui-options')[$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length ? 'slideDown' : 'slideUp']('fast');
});
```

```css
.ui-options {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="ui-options" />
<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="ui-options" />
<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="ui-options" />
<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="ui-options" />
<br />
<br />
<div class="ui-options">show me!</div>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6zsdLa5p/2/) for experimentation.

References:

- [`slideDown()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/).
- [`slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/).

Comment: Nice stuff, thanks for the solution, didn't know about "length" yet :)

Answer (score 2):

Using toggle, you are hiding/showing the div each time you click the checkbox. You need to check if there are any "checked" checkboxes and decide if you want to show or hide your div. For example like this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    if($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0)
        $(".ui-options").slideDown(150);
    else
        $(".ui-options").slideUp(150);
});
```

Comment: You should explain to him what he's doing wrong (or missing), and how you fixed it. =)